# SSAS Query Timeout Expired HYT00 Error, Runs fine in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, timeout, ssas

We have dimension I'm trying to process that times-out after running for about an hour. The dimension is intended to be used as a drill-through dimension and therefore is based on joins between 4 different tables (done within the SSAS project, not the source database).

The dimension also includes 30 attributes and of those attributes, there is one that is causing the timeout. When I take the query that is being used to process that attribute and run it in SQL Server directly, it only takes 10 minutes to run. However, when SSAS tries to run that query to process that attribute, it runs for about an hour and times-out with the error:

```
OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Query timeout expired; HYT00.
```

Why would it run for 10 mins in SQL Server and an hour in SSAS?

Comment: just some back ground please. how many rows in your dimension?, why is one attribute slowing this down?. why is the dimension a join between 4 tables and  not in the single dimension?.... and why not put the data from the 4  joins into a dump table at the very least to speed it up?